# Python and C extensions

Tags: python, python-c-api

This is an extension to my previous question found in
[C code within python and copying arrays in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204098/c-code-within-python-and-copying-arrays-in-c-code)

Serberg suggested I use PyArray_CopyInto functions from NUMPY. I am new to both python and C though I know a little bit of both. I am trying to learn how to fix the above problem and wondered what I could get some basic knowledge of C extensions?

I did look at the official page of python but its a bit difficult to understand for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about an official tutorial, but you should have a look at the following:

- any existing extensions
- the [C API documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/intro.html)

  - which also teaches about the concept of owning, stealing and borrowing references

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two sites:

1. [Array API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html)
2. [Array Iterator API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.iterator.html)

In the 2nd link take a look at the "Simple Multi-Iteration Example". It copies one array into another. In the 1st link, take a look at PyArray_NewCopy.