# equivalent of using #include <Numeric/arrayobject.h> in Numpy

Tags: python, c, numpy, scipy, numeric

I have an old piece of code and it uses Numeric and I wanted to swap that with numpy.

There is some C code too that uses the following:

```
    #include <Numeric/arrayobject.h>
```

I want to do the same using Numpy, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking for the closest equivalent to the same header, or for something you can use as a drop-in replacement so that old Numeric code will magically work as-is with Numpy?

Comment: Is there a replacement for it where I could update the code? The original code was written in python2.2 and looking at the numpy website its says that Numeric has been superceeded by numpy.

Comment: what can I do to use numpy instead of Numeric without losing the functionality of the code?

Comment: `#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>` My installation of Python has `arrayobject.h` at: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy`

Comment: that does not work as the paths are different -I am trying to understand the numpy/oldnumeric/alter_code1 to see if that can help

Comment: I think I might have fixed it-yes you are right Joel, it can be used provided I update the setup.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if anyone is interested -to continue to use arrayobject.h like in the old Numeric system

do the following:

```
      Replace <Numeric/arrayobject.h> with <numpy/arrayobject.h>
```

But the new arrayobject.h is in a different location to Numeric so update the setup.py as follows:

add the following

```
     import numpy as NU
```

Then under setup (still in setup.py) add the following

```
    include_dirs = [NU.get_include()],
```